# django pass response context none

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

In my browser, everything is fine. Until I make a test

here is my polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls.models import Poll

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'latest_poll_list':latest_poll_list}
    return render(request,'polls/index.html',context)
```

polls/templates/polls/index.html

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li>{{poll.question}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No Poll Available</p>
{% endif %}
```

and my polls/tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls.views.index'))
        print response.context
        print response.content
```

as you can see, my `response.context['latest_poll_list']` is always `[]`

*So I wonder where is my fault?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in the browser you get your objects this means that your view is ok, if your test does not return any object maybe you have to create them (tests make use of an empty database automatically created from the scratch by Django). I usually create sample objects in setUp() method:

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.poll = Poll.objects.create()
```

Comment: allright technically it's worked.
But I wonder, if I have a lot of tables do I have to create them one by one like this? Thanks

Comment: You can use fixtures, but normally you won't test against thousands of records, so is perfectly normal to create a couple of records for each test... you are writing UNIT tests, that is: the most simple and little piece of code in your application, you don't have to deal with the whole dataset :)

Comment: allright thanks sir for your answer



http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2010/1/28/1264689861868/Bow-001.jpg